# Adding time (sec and min) to a js var

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i've a question: in a JS file i have a variable (returned from an ajax call) that contains a time formatted in hh:mm:ss.

My question is: how can i add X minutes and X seconds to that time?

i tried in this mode:

```
var lastop = moment(data['lastOp']); //10:04:00
var summa = lastop.add(data['sessionLease'],'minutes');
```

But in consolle i receive this:

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Arguments: [object Object]
Error
    at Function.createFromInputFallback
```

How can i solve my problem?
Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`moment` with a format string](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), as the [issue that error message pointed you to](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407) told you to:

```
var lastop = moment(data['lastOp'], "HH:mm:ss");
```

...then add the minute and second:

```
lastop.add(1, "minute");
lastop.add(1, "second");
```

Example:

```js
var data = {
  lastOp: "10:04:00"
};
var lastop = moment(data['lastOp'], "HH:mm:ss");
lastop.add(1, "minute");
lastop.add(1, "second");
console.log(lastop.format("HH:mm:ss"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfctly!

Now i need to subtract actual time to a time variable (formatted in hh:mm:ss), for ex:

```
var time1 = 13:40:00

var time 2 = time1 - now time  // How can i do?
```